# Why is z-index not working for this webpage?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Open up http://irule.at/quovadis, and it will show you a regular theme. The problem is that the div photos is not showing up. It's most likely hiding behind body/html because of the z-index, but I want them to show behind the divs in the middle. How do I fix this?

Comment: There's probably an easier way to layout this page.  What's the photo div intended to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a negative z-index for photos. Instead of that, use a positive or 0 index, and give the other elements a higher index. Also remember that in order for z-index to work the elements should have `position: relative`. I got photos to show up by having it z-index 1, having header z-index 2 and position relative.

Comment: Nope, with position: absolute it seems to work too, and exactly as I wished it to, but this is the correct answer mainly, thanks

Comment: I didn't intend to say that it had to be relative. Just that it has to be something other than static, and relative is most commonly used for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You've had an answer, but thought I'd chip in a little to clear things up.

Z-indexing requires an element to be positioned, not necessarily `relative` or `absolute` as you've already figured out, but `fixed` is also an option.